# codeigniter return fetch data from controller to view via Ajax request

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, codeigniter

I load the view in Which I want to display fetch record from the database through the ajax JSON request.But it's not showing the record.

Here is my view code

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="hodm_table">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Task Name</th>
      <th>Director</th>
      <th>Duration</th> 
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <?php foreach($result as $hodm) { ?>
          <tr>
          <td><?php echo $hodm->t_name;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $hodm->director;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $hodm->duration;?></td>
          <td><?php echo $hodm->status;?></td>
      <?php } ?>
  </tbody>
</table> 
</div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
url:"<?php echo base_url();?>digital/dashboard/dig_short_hodm_table",
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'JSON',

success:function (data) {
  $('#hodm_table').html(data);
}

});
event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

Here is my model

```
public function get_hodm()
     {
          return $this->db->get("hodm");
     }
```

Here is my controller

```
public function dig_short_hodm_table(){

        $data['result']=$this->pojo->get_hodm();

        return json_encode($data);

     }
```

When I load my page then it showing the error

```
Message: Undefined variable: result
```

I want to when view load it fetch the record from the database and show in the view tables.

Comment: load a view page in controller function @xr33dx

Comment: @Parvez its not working

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your model:

```
public function get_hodm(){
      return $this->db->get("hodm")->result();
}
```

Your controller:

```
    public function dig_short_hodm_table(){    
    $result_html = '';
    $result_set = $this->pojo->get_hodm();

    foreach($result_set as $result) {
        $result_html .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $result->t_name . '</td>
                <td>' . $result->director . '</td>
                <td>' . $result->duration . '</td>
                <td>' . $result->status . '</td>
            </tr>';                   

    }

    echo json_encode($result_html);
}
```

Finally your view:

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="hodm_table">
    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Task Name</th>
                <th>Director</th>
                <th>Duration</th> 
                <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="hodm_results">

        </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>


<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>digital/dashboard/dig_short_hodm_table",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'JSON',

            success:function (data) {
                $('#hodm_results').html(data);
            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you give me a descriptive error message that you are getting?

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: result

Filename: digital/dashboard.php

Line Number: 38

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tmt_project\application\views\digital\dashboard.php
Line: 38
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tmt_project\application\controllers\digital\dashboard.php
Line: 17
Function: view

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\tmt_project\index.php
Line: 292
Function: require_once

Comment: I'll add another answer give me a few seconds

Comment: Ok, Thank you. I am waiting

Comment: $result_html .= '
            <tr>
                <td>' . $result->t_name . '</td>
                <td><?php echo $result->director . '</td>
                <td><?php echo $result->duration . '</td>
                <td><?php echo $result->status . '</td>
            </tr>';    I think there is some mistakes

Comment: Please click up to my question . I already mark your answer.. Thanx for help

Comment: I did . Please click up for my question also

Comment: @xr33dx You need to click on the Right Mark below the downvote button to accept as answer

Comment: Yes I did, Please click my question also

Comment: I'm only getting the last value from the database ?

Answer (score 0):

you must change like this

```
public function get_hodm()
 {
      return $this->db->get("hodm")->result();
 }
```

Comment: tell me what the problem or message?

Comment: i know the problem you just change $data['result'] with $data

Comment: first this message Message: Undefined variable: result blink then it show blank page

Comment: oh change this line to return json_encode($data); into echo json_encode($data);

Comment: what do you change and what the message, and do you know console? to detect your fault?

Comment: Undefined variable: result this are showing and in console it showing blank

Comment: do you change  $data['result'] into  $data ? on your controller?

Comment: yes I change but same error showing and then page goes blank

Comment: maybee you must set on your ajax console.log(data); on success section right

Comment: I didn't get you

Comment: what your mean?  console.log(data) is to detect, data and type from controller

Comment: Object
result
:
Array(58)
0
:
Object
date
:
"2016-09-30"
director
:
"Ameesha Mam"
duration
:
"0.7"
id
:
"6"
partner
:
"suneet"
status
:
"Done"
t_name
:
"LI-Emailers"
task
:
"Working on LI Emailers with suneet for triggering as suggested by ameesha mam"
update_by
:
""
updated_at
:
"0000-00-00 00:00:00"
user_name
:
"om"
__proto__
:
Object   console output

Comment: the meaning is your success from controller into view, it just looping on view like this

$.each(data, function(index, val) {$('#hodm_table').append(val.director)});

Answer (score 0):

I have update Model View and Controller:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    url:"<?php echo base_url();?>digital/dashboard/dig_short_hodm_table",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'JSON',

    success:function (data) {
        var result = data.result;'
        var row = "";
        for(i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
            row += "<tr>";
            row += "<td>"+result[i].t_name+"</td>";
            row += "<td>"+result[i].director+"</td>";
            row += "<td>"+result[i].duration+"</td>";
            row += "<td>"+result[i].status+"</td>";
            row += "</tr>";
        }
        $('#hodm_table > tbody').html(row);
    }

});
event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

**Here is my model**

```
public function get_hodm()
{
    $query = $this->db->get("hodm");
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

**Here is my controller**

```
public function dig_short_hodm_table(){

    $data['result']=$this->pojo->get_hodm();

    echo json_encode($data);

}
```

Comment: Can you check in console? what response are you getting

Comment: I got the answer thanks for help. I prefer theEUG answer

Answer (score 0):

try to return in controller like this by changing header content

```
public function dig_short_hodm_table(){
header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
$data['result']=$this->pojo->get_hodm();
echo(json_encode($data));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Change Your Model Like Below

```
public function get_hodm()
{
    $query = $this->db->get("hodm");
    return $query -> result();
}
```